# German phrase for 'suited and booted'

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

What is a German phrase for the English phrase 'suited and booted' meaning that someone or a group of people are prepared, have the necessary equipment, etc.

Comment: I've always heard "suited and booted" referred to as being dressed-up, usually for a special occasion. Are you sure that's the correct phrase?

Comment: I am with you on that, Kenneth (+1). I have only ever heard it as dressed up, and never as the OP suggests.

Comment: I'm from Midlands, UK. And we use the saying to refer to all kinds of things like when someone is going camping for example and they have their tent, stove, etc. I would expect that you would've only have known of the dictionary definition but there are a few other meanings which go unheard of.

Comment: "ready to go" is (maybe depressingly) common.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably the most literal translation, which also fits from the "temperature" is

> gestiefelt und gespornt

(literally "booted and spurred"). This has, like the English, a military background.

Comment: That is exactly what immediately sprang to my mind when I read the question, before I scrolled down to the answers.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for terms related to *der Abmarsch*.

> Los, Abmarsch!

It's the departure of a larger group from one location. As soon they begin to move, it's hard to have them come to a halt again so you better be *suited and booted* before you do it. This is checked with the adjective *abmarschbereit*:

> Macht euch abmarschbereit!
>
> Alles abmarschbereit?
>
> Wir sind abmarschbereit.

It sounds a bit militaristic, by purpose. It's the only way to tame a swarm of children.

Comment: The word "Abmarsch!" is better described as "Go!", not as being prepared.

Comment: I included it to explain this complicated word *abmarschbereit*.

Comment: "Klar zum Abmarsch" wäre vermutlich das 1:1 equivalent zu "suited and booted".

Answer (score 6):

> xxx stehen (plural)/steht (singular) auf Abruf bereit

would be matching, but is probably a more general term, since it would also fit to the loan a bank offers to you, a rented car. It has no military background.

> Gestiefelt und gespornt

would be close also mentioning boots, but could be used for persons.

Answer (score 6):

Ich kenne noch

- die Pferde sind gesattelt
- gesattelt und gespornt
- gesattelt und gestriegelt (die Pferde sind ~)

sowie, neben dem bereits genannten

- abmarschbereit
- abflugbereit
- bereit zum Aufbruch

Man kann aber aus verschiedensten Kontexten entsprechende Redewendungen übernehmen, etwa

- der Patient ist jetzt operationsbereit
- der Ball liegt im Anstoßkreis
- der Motor ist warmgelaufen
- die Rakete wartet auf den Countdown

Comment: For a less militaristic touch there's also "aufbruchbereit"

Comment: @infinitezero: Umformuliert aufgenommen.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a phrase meaning "ready to go", another pretty common one would be

> Gewehr bei Fuß stehen

The literal translation would be something like "standing with gun at hand", the phrase originates from military jargon. In civil life it is for example used in an exchange like this:

> "Ich hole dich in 10 Minuten ab. Sei bitte fertig, wir haben es eilig"
>
> "In Ordnung, ich stehe Gewehr bei Fuß"